# Standard Controller with Lightning

Tags: standardcontroller, lightning-aura-components

Is there a possibility where I can create a Lightning Component without writing a Custom APEX Controller?

For example in Visualforce page we could use a StandardController and implement a standard functionality without writing a single line of APEX code.

If that's not possible for now, is this something being considered? For example I can see something similar with

force:recordView 
force:recordEdit

but its no where close to the StandardController feature set.

Comment: This community has decided that "lightning" is too vague a tag as it is brand-related and can mean several different features: Process Builder, Community Builder, Lightning Components, App Builder, Schema Builder are all under the "Lightning" brand umbrella. Consequently I removed the "lightning" tag. Also, even though you refer to Visualforce, this question is really about Lightning Components. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not exist as of the current state of the beta of Lightning Component Framework in the Spring 15 release.

Of course, we cannot guarantee a feature will exist before it goes GA, but this functionality is high on the priority list for features when Lightning Components goes GA.